# Getting concurrent jobs running in Quartz.Net with clustering set to disallowed in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, cluster-computing, quartz.net

I have a test harness which is scheduling a total of 15 jobs.  I have configured the test harness to use sql server clustering.  Three of the jobs use listeners to launch two other jobs each upon successful completion (so there are 3 "parent" jobs, 6 "child" jobs, and 6 "singular" jobs).

To simulate the actual work I put a random sleep in each of the job of 5 to 10 seconds, with the parent jobs triggered by cron on 10 second intervals.  This would ensure that clashes were likely to occur on a single node and that some jobs would start late or overrun others.

To test this I limited the concurrency to 3 and launched two of the parent jobs.

Before I added DI to the harness it all worked beautifully.  The first node would show problems (in the console) and shortly after I fired up a second node, the problems would fade away to almost nothing, jobs would be spread across the two nodes as expected.

However, after adding DI and reworking the initialisation I am seeing the same jobs running up on both nodes at the same time, clearly I don't have the clustering configured right.  I am seeing this in the log when I start and stop the second node...

```
info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0]
      Quartz Scheduler 3.6.3.0 - 'node1' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED' initialized info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0]
      Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool', size: 3 info: Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory[0]
      Using job store 'Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX', supports persistence: True, clustered: True info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down... info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]

...data...

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      Scheduler node1_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      Scheduler node1_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
info: Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler[0]
      Scheduler node1_$_NON_CLUSTERED Shutdown complete.
```

The code where I setup Quartz is as follows (I have left out the job, trigger and listener setup for brevity)...

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // Add dependency injection.
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory(options =>
    {
    });

    q.SchedulerName = node;

    q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.PerformSchemaValidation = true;
        s.UseProperties = true; 

        q.UseDefaultThreadPool(tp =>
        {
            tp.MaxConcurrency = 3;                                
        });

        s.UseSqlServer(sqlServer =>
        {
            sqlServer.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=quartz;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true";   
            sqlServer.TablePrefix = "QRTZ_";
        });

        s.UseJsonSerializer();
        s.UseClustering(c =>
        {
            c.CheckinMisfireThreshold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);      
            c.CheckinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);              
        });
    });
   services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
   {
       options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
   });
})
.Build()
.RunAsync();
```

All the dummy task classes have been give the [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute but this is clearly an issue with the two nodes not realising they're clustered, they're both using the common database but aren't coordinating their actions.

The database is correctly configured because it verifies it at start and it's the same one that worked in the non-DI version.  I've tried wiping the database tables for good measure but that makes no difference, I just can't seem to find why the nodes aren't clustering.

Any help would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, despite both nodes having different values for the `node` variable, if I remove the line `q.SchedulerName = node;` it seems to behave. Not sure what is going on here but might have made progress.

It appears that just not naming the scheduler, it just works as it should.

The logs still show NON_CLUSTERED in the scheduler names but this appears to have fixed it.  Hope that helps someone.